# bash script to run jupyter notebook in virtualenv

Tags: bash, automation, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

To speed up launching projects I created a small bash script which does the following:

- takes an argument (project name)
- moves to the directory of that project
- starts a virtual environment
- starts a jupyter notebook

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "k3" ]; then
    project_path="tau-code/k3-analysis/"
fi

codepath="/media/peter/somedrive/code"
full_path="$codepath/$project_path"

# Go to directory of project
cd $full_path

# Start environment & notebook if available
pipenv shell
jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0
```

It activates the environment, but does not run the `jupyter` command.  When I exit the environment I see the error:

> `line 16: jupyter: command not found`

I can manually type `jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0` in my newly created environment and that does work.

What may be the problem?

Comment: can manally you check `which jupyter`  in newly created environment ? and manually run `env` in newly created environment ?  
also same in your bash script after - pipenv shell
`pipenv shell`  
`env` 
`jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0`    i somewhere think its a path issue..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pipenv shell` starts a new shell which must be deactivated by using `exit`. In your script any commands following the call to `pipenv shell` are not executed in that new shell. Instead they are executed in the same bash shell after the virtual environment shell is closed. You should use `pipenv run jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0`

See [pipenv documentation](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/#other-commands):

> - `shell` will spawn a shell with the virtualenv activated. This shell can be deactivated by using `exit`.
> - `run` will run a given command from the virtualenv, with any arguments forwarded (e.g. `$ pipenv run python` or `$ pipenv run pip freeze`).

Answer (score 1):

Hi you need to add this

```
pipenv run jupyter notebook
```